# VB version of C# razor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having trouble translating the following c#/Razor template into VB

```
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Date.ToShortDateString()), 
    new { @class = "datefield" })
```

Specifically, how do I translate the @class

```
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Date.ToShortDateString(), New With { @class = "datefield" })
```

gives the error `BC30201: Expression expected.`

Comment: I dont think the '@' symbol is used in VB.NET. Try removing that... .class = "datefield".

Comment: [keyword] is the VB way of escaping keywords in the same way c# uses @

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
Html.TextBox("", [String].Format("{0:d}", Model.[Date].ToShortDateString()), New With {.[class] = "datefield"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the brackets, they are not necessary:

```
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Date.ToShortDateString()), New With {.class = "datefield"})
```

The Telerik converter works well, but converting Razor syntax leaves a lot to be desired. :)